# Rest angular Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: angularjs, rest, ngresource

me da este error :

> Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen
>   impide leer el recurso remoto en http://localhost:8090/test/databases
>   (razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin').

Mi servidor es una aplicación `Java` en un `tomcat 8`

En otro proyecto tengo esto :

```
var App = angular.module('SimulatorApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);
App.controller('EOGController', ['$scope','$resource',function($scope, $resource) { 
    $scope.loadData = function() {
        var Something = $resource("http://localhost:8090/test/databases/test", {id: "@id"});
        $scope.something = Something.get({id:15});                                          
    }   
}]);
```

Realmente si llama, me da código 200 pero el error que mencionaba antes.

SI lo llamo desde poster me funciona sin problemas o si en el navegador pongo la `url : http://localhost:8090/test/databases/test?id=15 tb funciona`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando desde tu sitio AngularJS intentas acceder a tu sitio en el servidor, este puede responder que no de todos los sitios es posible acceder a estos datos, `Origin` es un dominio, todo esto por defecto viene inaccesible desde otro origen que no sea el original.

Agrega a tu servidor

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers, Last-Modified</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Y desde el llamado de tu AngularJS agrega `contentType`

```
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;"
```

Asi :

```
$http({
     method: 'GET',
     url: 'http://localhost:8090/test/databases/test',
     params: {id: "@id"},
     contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

}).then(function success(response) {

}, function error(response) {

});
```

Comment: He agregado la linea tanto en el web.xml de mi servidor tomcat como en el web.xml de mi aplicación web java

Comment: @Jose elimina dataType : json

Comment: Realmente no tenia que hacer eso, pero me has ayudado para saber por donde tirar, lo soluciones con lo siguiente :

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846309/cors-filter-not-working-as-intended

Comment: ha! el problema tambien estaba del lado de tu aplicación, que bueno que lo hayas solucionado!

Comment: solo otra pregunta mas 
}).then(function success(response) {

});

eso es si sale bien, pero si tengo error? como lo capturo?

Comment: Antes era success y error, ahora es then, ahi vas a poder capturar tanto el error como el exito, sin embargo hay un error. Voy a actualizar!

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar solicitudes cruzadas, el host debe explicitamente permitir una solicitud desde el referer cliente. Por lo que debes añadir la siguiente cabecera:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://sitio-del-request.com
```

donde sitio-del-request.com es el sitio que ejecuta la solicitud.

Con esto quiero decir que el problema no esta en Angular, si no en el servidor en Java.

Answer (score 0):

@sioesi He agregado la linea tanto en el web.xml de mi servidor tomcat como en el web.xml de mi aplicación web java

```
var Something = $resource("http://localhost:8090/test/databases/test", {id: "@id"});
$scope.something = Something.get({id:15});

Me sigue dando el mismo problema
```

He probado con lo tuyo :
App.controller('EOGController', ['$scope', '$http', '$resource', function($scope, $http, $resource) {
....
    $http({
             method: 'GET',
             url: 'http://localhost:8090/test/databases/test',
             params: {id: "@id"},
             dataType: "json",
             contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

```
    }).then(function success(response) {
        $scope.something = Something.get({id:15});  
    });
```

Error 400: Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en http://localhost:8090/test/databases/test?id=@id (razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin').